# Golang SQL table JOIN into slice field

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

Consider the following tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE bar (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE foo_bar_members (
  foo_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES foo(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  bar_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES bar(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY (foo_id, bar_id)
)
```

`foo_bar_members` is a relations table that connects `foo` and `bar`. View `foo` as the parent of `bar`. And I have the following Go struct:

```golang
type Foo struct {
  ID     int `db:"id"`
  BarIDs []int
}
```

`BarIDs` is a slice of `bar.id` that is associated with this `foo` by `foo.id`. I want to query for something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM foo f INNER JOIN foo_bar_members fbm ON f.id = fbm.foo_id WHERE f.id = $1
```

But this query is just an example. Obvious this won't scan into `Foo.BarIDs`. I could always do two separate queries but I'm wondering if there are better ways. I'm using [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL, the left join here will also return foos that don't have no bars associated.

```
select
    foo.id
    , array_agg(bar.id)
from foo
left join foo_bar_members m on m.foo_id = foo.id
where foo.id = $1
group by foo.id
```

If you care only about foos that have bars, then there's no need for the join actually.

```
select
    m.foo_id
    , array_agg(m.bar_id)
from foo_bar_members m
where m.foo_id = $1
group by m.foo_id
```

The go code:

```
const sql = "<one of the queries from above>"

f := new(Foo)
if err := db.QueryRow(sql, 123).Scan(&f.ID, pq.Array(&f.BarIDs)); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

---

[`pq.Array`](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Array) is a function that returns a value that implements the `sql.Scanner` and `driver.Valuer` interfaces and the implementation knows how to scan a postgres array into a go slice or turn a go slice into a postgres array.

---

I'm not familiar with `sqlx` so it's possible it itself provides some feature that allows you to scan arrays and therefore the use of `pq.Array` might be unnecessary. Maybe someone who know better will eventually provide their version of the solution.